# Javascript - Get text from display version of multiline field

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-form

I need to get the text from a multi-line field in display mode on a custom form. SharePoint decides to wrap the text in an extra div which is not on the `.aspx` page which is causing the problem as I can not give it an ID.

The html is rendered as this:

```
< td class="ms-formbody" id="allowances" valign="top" width="400px"><div dir="">THIS TEXT HERE< /div >< /td>
```

When I use `.innerHTML` it comes with the `< div>` tag. InnerText returns nothing.

What is the best way to return only THIS TEXT HERE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `queryselector` to reach the text inside the div:

```
var textValue = document.querySelector("#allowances div").innerText;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Only thing is that I needed to change it to innerHTML.

Comment: Complex Selectors are resource heavy so this is faster: ``var textValue = document.getElementById("allowances").firstChild.innerHTML;``